# Practical rate (e.g. kg/day) that carbon could be harvested from CO2 in the Martian atmosphere and climate?

Tags: mars, colonization, mining

There is frequent discussion of using CO2 in the Martian atmosphere to synthesize carbon-containing compounds. One example is methane for propulsion, another:  [Can materials be found to make plastic on Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2569/12102), but given the very low pressure out there, what might be a practical rate that you could extract carbon from Mars' atmosphere?

Is atmospheric extraction without question the way to go, or would you rather opt to mine solid, subsurface CO2 ice for this reason?

UPD [a recent NASA ISRU document](https://www.fbo.gov/index?s=opportunity&mode=form&tab=core&id=a6881f54f334e5676e9e5a36b4e4f085) lists for example for other substances following rates: *per module production rates are 1.1 kg O2/hr for O2 only from the
atmosphere, and 1.35 kg O2/hr and 0.34 kg CH4/hr for O2 and CH4 from the atmosphere and soil
water*.